# Negate all list values in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, list-comprehension

The following two versions of my script work as intended:

```
matrix = [[1, -2, 3], [-4, 5, -6], [7, -8, 9]]


def negate(amatrix):
    for alist in matrix:
        for i in range(len(alist)):
            alist[i] = -alist[i]
    return amatrix

print(negate(matrix))
```

Yields:  [[-1, 2, -3], [4, -5, 6], [-7, 8, -9]]

as does this version:

```
matrix = [[1, -2, 3], [-4, 5, -6], [7, -8, 9]]


def negate(amatrix):
    newmatrix = []
    for alist in amatrix:
        newlist = [-x for x in alist]
        newmatrix.append(newlist)
    return newmatrix

print(negate(matrix))
```

I am trying to use a comprehension to change the values in place, like the first version.

I have this:

```
matrix = [[1, -2, 3], [-4, 5, -6], [7, -8, 9]]


def negate(amatrix):
    for alist in matrix:
        alist = [-x for x in alist]
    return amatrix

print(negate(matrix))
```

This third version does negate the individual values in each of the lists, but the changes are not saved in the matrix, i.e., I want the list values changed in place.

Is there a way to use a comprehension to negate the individual list values in place, or do I have to use the indexed version (the first version above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions do not work in place. When you say `x = [-i for i in x]`, the right hand side is evaluated first and assigned to `x`. Even if you are assigning it to the same variable, the solution is not in-place.

What you may want is a vectorised in-place solution. This is supported by `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, -2, 3], [-4, 5, -6], [7, -8, 9]])

arr *= -1

# array([[-1,  2, -3],
#        [ 4, -5,  6],
#        [-7,  8, -9]])
```

Comment: "List comprehensions do not work in place."  That is what I needed to know.

Comment: Turns out you can.   `matrix = [[1, -2, 3], [-4, 5, -6], [7, -8, 9]]


def negate(amatrix):
    amatrix = [[-x for x in alist] for alist in amatrix]
    return amatrix

print(negate(matrix))
`

Comment: Yes, but this isn't an in place solution. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: You're right.  I thought it was in place.  It's not.  Just shorter.